# How to create a directory in linux application server using oracle forms 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracleforms

I have a requirement to create a directory at run time in linux application server and create a report in that directory. I'm using the below command but its not working. Can you please advise?

```
webutil_host.host('mkdir  -p '||'/BEE/temp/rdf');
```

Comment: As always "not working" is not a helpful error message.  What is the _actual_ error message?  Personally I'd question the "requirement" of creating directories at run time.  If that is a "requirement", then I'd question the application design that that makes it  a requirement.

Comment: There seems no problem with the command provided that you have changed to the desired directory before this, except for using the pipe concatenation part `'||'` is redundant, but are you sure that you really attached the `webutil_host` library? What do you see when you compile(when pressing `Ctrl+K`, then `Ctrl+T`) the forms at the design time?

Comment: I have attached webutil library to fmb  and Form is getting compiled without any compilation issue. Even I'm able to test the webutil_demo fmb without any issues.

Comment: Can someone please advise ?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in your Oracle Forum post, WebUtil is for working with function on the user tier.  So unless your user is running a Unix/Linux OS, you code won’t work.  Remove the Webutil part of the call and just use HOST.

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4483447/not-able-to-create-a-directory-in-linux-application-server-using-oracle-forms-12c

Also, as some mentioned above, it is unclear why you have the pipes in you code.